# Best way to scale an image if it's too small like pinterest does?

Tags: php, image, pinterest

How does pinterest rescales their images? Even if you upload a 16x16 icon, it will rescale it but make it look smooth.. Does anyone know how they how their resize mechanism works?

Comment: Shouldn't the question have to be: if the image is too small?

Comment: Could you post an example screenshot of how it looks on Pinterest when you've uploaded the small image?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat here is an example of 16x16 pixel and how they resized it http://postimage.org/image/m7zsvqgkb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you provided looks like they simply set the height of the image to be the height of the container, i.e. in the `height` attribute of the `<img>` tag. I wouldn't say it looks smooth at all, plus the aspect ratio is obviously way off.

But if you want to resize images in PHP yourself, there are several image libraries like GD. Take a look at the [imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) function (there is some example code on that page) or search for some tutorials.